# Add padding to FrameLayout programmatically without moving inner Fragment with ScrollView content

Tags: android, scrollview

I need to add bottom padding or margin to the `FrameLayout`in an `Activity` programmatically after some delay. Problem is that it is container for `Fragments` with `ScrollView`. When I set bottom padding/margin to it inner content is scrolled upwards. Top part of `Fragment` content is not visible anymore.

It works well when I set bottom padding to `ScrollView` content but I want to avoid that and handle it in an `Activity` without need to modify every single `Fragment`.

I tried:

- set bottom margin/padding to `FrameLayout`
- put `View` at the bottom of `FrameLayout` in `LinearLayout`,
- set `android:clipToPadding="false"` to `ScrollView`.

The same behaviour every time. Any ideas?

Comment: How about manually setting the height of your `ScrollView` by changing it from (I assume) `match_parent` to a fixed value, computed in run-time, out of the height of the parent **minus** the padding value?

Comment: And what's the desired outcome anyway? I mean, the contents of your `ScrollView` won't fully fit on the screen once the padding is added, right? I take it you're okay with that. If that's the case, is it only about the `ScrollView` getting scrolled to the bottom, and cutting the top part off? If I'm not mistaken, `scrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS)` should stop this autoscroll to the bottom. If I'm misunderstanding you still, please clarify!

Comment: As I wrote from the `Activity` I have access only to the `FrameLayout` which is container for `Fragments` that can contain for example `ScrollView`, `RecyclerView` etc. I don't want to modify every `Fragment` I already have and all I will add in the future.
Content should fulfill whole view without bottom padding/margin. It works fine but after set of margin/padding to `FrameLayout` inner `ScrollView` just scrolls content by that padding/margin towards top. I will check `scrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS)`

Comment: @KonradMorawski `scrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS)` didn't help. It is not scrolled by children, it scrolls because container is resized.

Comment: Right... I have no time to pursue it further, but if I were you I'd probably try subclassing `ScrollView` and overriding some of its methods related to the behaviour you're bumping into, debugging how they work to catch the moment where that thing happens etc. My first culprit would be `onSizeChanged` with that `doScrollY` call, but it's just an (un)educated guess : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have still problem you can use :

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

In your child ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out it by myself. It seems that this is issue occurs when`setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true)`is used with`setFadingEdgeLength()` on`ScrollView`.

This hack solved the issue:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
}
```